# How to Change background Colour of Textbox Using a Button

Tags: excel, vba, colors, textbox

I am trying to create an Excel file where I have a macro that changes the fill colour of a textbox. This macro would be activated when the user clicks on a Button (Form Control). I am fairly new to VBA (and programming in general), and am having trouble writing the code for this. I've looked through other forums and tried applying what I read, but everybody seems to solve the problems using different code structure and/or syntax. The logic for my code is essentially as follows:

User clicks on button to activate macro:

```
If TextBox1 BackColor = RGB (191, 191, 191) 

     Then TextBox1 BackColor = RGB(242, 242, 242)

Else if TextBox BackColor = RGB(242, 242, 242)

     Then TextBox1 BackColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
```

Comment: Fire up the macro recorder, change the text box color and take it from there. The exact VBA will vary with the Excel version used. Pre 2007 is different from 2007 and up.

Comment: Put a period between "TextBox1" and "BackColor" like `TextBox1.BackColor`. Also, `ElseIf` is one word. Like @teylyn says, the Macro Recorder will reveal that and other helpful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and this should work for you.  I attached it to a button and it worked fine:

```
If TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(191, 191, 191) Then
     TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(242, 242, 242)
ElseIf TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(242, 242, 242) Then
     TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
End If
```

You use the dot (.) to get to an object's properties, so TextBox1.BackColor.